# Using angularJS filter to search in another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to use the Angular filter on ng-repeat to search in another object, not the object used in the ng-repeat. Can I do that or there is a better way to do that.

Here is a Plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/f9p8eNhxDV3Tg56bpVGI?p=preview).

I want to search in the all_data object not sample_data.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Duplicate data is not optimal..Why not just repeat over the all_data? And for all I know I don't think it is possible.

Comment: You may need to write a custom filter. What are you trying to achieve by displaying one array and filtering another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this trick:

```
<div ng-init="filteredItems = all_data"/>

<input ng-model="searchText" ng-change="filteredItems = (all_data | filter: searchText)">
```

At start, `filteredItems` equals `all_data`. When input `searchText` changed, `filteredItems` changed too.

You can use `{{filteredItems}}` on the view, and `$scope.filteredItems` in the controller.

I adjust your plunker, please see it.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GhRD22cNgaW4gGPFr0GF?p=preview)